# how to use python imaging library for web based image editor

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-imaging-library

I want to use PIL Library for image processing for a web based image editor. Can you share your thought as how to proceed, if not PIL which library to use .

Note: Please suggest libraries for JavaScript or Python.

Comment: It is very difficult to see a specific focus in here. What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: i m looking to integrate PIL to my web based image editor, to handle more complex task, but i am not able to understand as how to implement it

Comment: do you want real-time, or on submission???  Also, what kind of server backend are you using (python I am assuming)?

Comment: realtime and server backend is python

Comment: realtime may be difficult...only thing I can think of is to have a user interaction send info to your server, the server runs the PIL stuff, renders a new image, and sends the link back for the page to display...this could be really slow...You could try to make an editor using canvas...[simple paint program example here](http://caimansys.com/painter/)

Answer (score 1):

I would use JavaScript if you want to edit in realtime, otherwise you will have to be pretty tricky in order to not overwhelm your HTTP connection.